# Add new functionality to mean in Statistics.jl

Tags: statistics, julia

There has been a proposal to extend the functionality of `median` in `Statistics.jl` by adding a function such that the first parameter is a function, following the style of, for example, `mean(abs, v)`. In such a case, it should be understood that the functionality of the `quantile` functions should also be extended, although as far as I can see, `mean` is not implemented using quantile. Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, the following looks like a good implementation for both `median` and `quantile`:

```
using MappedArrays
using Statistics

v = randn(10)

@show median(abs.(v))
@show median(mappedarray(abs, v))
```

giving:

```
median(abs.(v)) = 0.3167044909082123

median(mappedarray(abs, v)) = 0.3167044909082123
```

The MappedArray version does not need to materialize a new `v`-length array and looks very close to the considered `median(abs, v)`.